# How we make more instances from a variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, instance

I would like to generate instances from a class with a variable.

I am opening and reading a text file, and I would like to generate an instance every time I find a special text. So if I find the  'Wall' word, I like to make an instance which will be, Wall01 and then for the second time Wall02 and so forth.

```
class ifc_wall(object):
    ...

list = [23,45,67,98] #these should be the wall numbers
for wall_number in list:
    ("string: WALL" + wall_number) = ifc_wall(wall_number) #???
```

I am having a hard time with ??? part, and couldn't find a solution on the forums. And I would like to use basic python code without any imported stuff. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you just store these in a dictionary where the key is the 'Wall..' name and value is the instance?

Comment: Don't create variables with dynamic names, **use a container**

Comment: A dict I think is not enough, cause one wall, forex. Wall-02 will have several attributes, so I need several objects, but dont know how to create these with code.

What kind of container you mean?